# Configure WebApp2 request and response. Create and close session objects along them

Tags: sqlalchemy, webapp2

I am creating a webapp2, SQLalchemy, postgresql based web application.

My question is: *How to create the SQLAlchemy session object (scoped_session) whenever a request comes and close the same object while sending the response.*

Going through the docs I understood that this is the best possible method of creating and closing the session object. But how to achieve it with WebApp2 I am not sure. If someone knows a better and efficient way of doing it then please let me know.

Currently I am creating a scoped_session obj in a config file and I import this file and use the obj wherever needed. I have not closed the object anywhere which I guess is not a good practice. What I want to achieve is whenever there is a request from browser, I get a new session object, use this session object to interact with database and when response is returned close the session object.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Overriding dispatch()](https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/handlers.html#overriding-dispatch) seems to be the way to go:

```
class MyHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def dispatch(self):
        try:
            ret = webapp2.RequestHandler.dispatch(self)
            Session().commit()
            return ret
        except:
            Session().rollback()
            raise
```

This assume that you have something like this: `Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker())` so `Session()` always returns the threadlocal session.

Note: I don't know webapp2 and so I am not sure if this is exactly the right place. For example, I'm not sure if there may be an exception handler in the `dispatch` call of the parent class. So you might need a similar technique on a different place (or another way to detect an error here).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out towards right direction. I feel playing with webapp2 request handler's dispatch function will solve my purpose. I implemented the change but in some cases i receive a closed session object.

Comment: Normally, sessions don't close automatically. Try to find any instantiation of session and follow its use. Maybe you use calls like `close`, `commit` or `rollback`. Refactor them out. Also pay attention to context managers like `with session.begin()`. This could cause problems here and is most likely not required.

Comment: is there a way to put the Session() in a cached property for webapp2